# TCPDF getting spacing issue with writeHTML

Tags: php, tcpdf

I am using html to create pdf. Below is my code:

```
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);


$pdf->SetMargins(15, 20, 14, 0);
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, 0);
$pdf->setCellPaddings(0,0,0,0);
$pdf->setFooterMargin(0);
$pdf->setPrintHeader(false);
$pdf->setPrintFooter(false);

// add a page
$pdf->AddPage();

    $html = '
    <div style="background-color: #f8f8f8;">

    <div style="font-size: 24px; color: #333; font-weight: 600; font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;">Example</div>

    <p style="color: #828282; font-size: 14px; font-family: sans-serif;">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
    Lorem Ipsum has been the industry standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, 
    when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type
    specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap 
    into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised 
    in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages,
    and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including 
    versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  </div>';

$pdf->writeHTML($html, false, false, true, false, '');

$pdf->Output('example_001.pdf', 'I');
```

For some reason there is a space between heading and text as you can see[image]

Also, whenever i add line-height style to make some space between lines in paragraph, it just leaves even more gap.

Comment: Did you try to put `margin:0;padding:0;` style to text paragraph and `div` that contains `Example` ?

Comment: `<p>` has default margin for both bot and top, I expect that TCPDF consider them by default. Try to add `margin:0;` in your `<p>` style.

Comment: I added both `margin:0;padding:0;` in both `p and div` tags but still not reducing space. @Frankich @Lounis

Comment: `$tagvs = array('p' => array(0 => array('h' => 0, 'n' => 0), 1 => array('h' => 0, 'n' => 0))); $pdf->setHtmlVSpace($tagvs);` Could you try to add those 2 lines ? looks like the `margin` is not suported as CSS properties with TCPDF. https://tcpdf.org/examples/example_061/ .

Comment: Working fine now, thanks @Frankich

Comment: Frankich - YOU ARE AWESOME!!! Your suggestion worked for me like charm. Thanks a lot dear :)

Answer (score 3):

The solution is as @Frankich commented:

```
$tagvs = [
    'div' => [
        0 => ['h' => 0, 'n' => 0],
        1 => ['h' => 0, 'n' => 0]
    ],
    'p' => [
        0 => ['h' => 0, 'n' => 0],
        1 => ['h' => 0, 'n' => 0]
    ]
];
$pdf->setHtmlVSpace($tagvs);
```

Documentation:
https://tcpdf.org/docs/srcdoc/TCPDF/classes-TCPDF/#method_setHtmlVSpace